# Get the value in the line above a word

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the text below and would like to get the value of the line above the word 
 `OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES` in this case the value `8.571.962,06`

I did the following, but I found you very vulnerable.

```
^(.?)\s(?(\d+.\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+,\d+))\sOUTRAS INFORMA.?.*?ES
```

OCR:

```
NOME: TESTE DE SILVA SAURO
CPF: 785.981.970-84
DECLARAÇÃO DE AJUSTE ANUAL
IMPOSTO SOBRE A RENDA - PESSOA FÍSICA
EXERCICIO 2018 ANO-CALENDÁRIO 2017
EVOLUÇÃO PATRIMONIAL
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2016
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2017
Dividas conus rcais em 31/12/2016
Divisas e ônus reais em 31/12/2017
100.580.873.91
100.329. 110,32
9135,456,07
8.571.962,06
OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES
Rendimentos isentos e não tributáveis
```

I'm using sitging to test https://regexr.com/

Comment: the `(?(`-syntax at the start of the second capture group is unfamiliar to me. in which situations did you find this regex vulnerable and when did it work?

Comment: Does the value you're looking for always fill the whole line? If so, you can just use `^.+(?=\sOUTRAS INFORMA)`.

Comment: Yes, it always fills the whole line. I'm using the site https://regexr.com/ for testing and it did not work this way.

Comment: You need to enable the multiline flag at the right top under "flags"

Answer (score 1):

This should do it ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5sqSrD/1/))

```
^.*(?=\nOUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES)
```

Basically, do a lookahead to find a newline character with after it the `OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES` line